# How does indexing with comma work on Python's plt?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, plot, k-means

I was following a Machine Learning course, having basic knowledge of Python, following an example in Towards Data Science about *K-means Clustering* and there is a way of indexing that I didn't ask the professor during the lecture.
[Source](https://towardsdatascience.com/k-means-clustering-with-scikit-learn-6b47a369a83c)
It's the part where the graph is plotted, with the centroids, the author uses indexing like:

```
plt.scatter(
    X[y_km == 2, 0], X[y_km == 2, 1],
    s=50, c='lightblue',
    marker='v', edgecolor='black',
    label='cluster 3'
)
```

Does anybody know how this works?

I've tried doing it outside of the `plt.scatter`, and it isn't helping further than what I already know.

Comment: "Python's plt" isn't a thing. Do you mean `matplotlib.pyplot`? It's often imported _as_ `plt`, but that's not what it's called.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, I'm sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough but yeah, I was refering to the matplotlib library. I tried to add a tag to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X` is an array of 2 columns. You can think of them as `x` and `y` coordinates. 
By printing the first 10 rows, you see:

```
print(X[0:10])

[[ 2.60509732  1.22529553]
 [ 0.5323772   3.31338909]
 [ 0.802314    4.38196181]
 [ 0.5285368   4.49723858]
 [ 2.61858548  0.35769791]
 [ 1.59141542  4.90497725]
 [ 1.74265969  5.03846671]
 [ 2.37533328  0.08918564]
 [-2.12133364  2.66447408]
 [ 1.72039618  5.25173192]]
```

`y_km` is the classification of these coordinates.
In the example, they are either classified as `0`, `1`, or `2`

```
print(y_km[0:10])

[1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 0]
```

But when you have `y_km == 1`, these are converted to a list of Booleans

```
print((y_km==1)[0:10])

[ True False False False True False False True False False]
```

So when you call

`X[y_km == 1 , 1]`

Essentially, you are asking to select the values of `y_km` that are equal to `1`, and map them to column `1` of the X array. It will only grab the rows for which `y_km` is equal to True, and only grab the value from the column specified (i.e. 1)

And

`X[y_km == 2, 0]`

The values of y_km that are equal to `2`, mapped to column `0` of the X array.

So the first number relates to the classification group that you want to gather, and the second number relates to the column of the X array that you want to retrieve from.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article that can help you understand ndarray indexing better: [Indexing on ndarrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)

So in your example `X` is 2dim ndarray with n rows and 2 columns - *feature1* and *feature2*.
Simple example:

```
x = np.arange(20).reshape(10, 2)

array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13],
       [14, 15],
       [16, 17],
       [18, 19]])
```

and simple example of `y` - list of classes:

```
y = np.array([1, 2] * 5)
array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])
```

Let's consider you want to get all rows from X array which correspond to class 1.
You can simply do this using **boolean array indexing** like this:

```
x[y == 1]

array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 8,  9],
       [12, 13],
       [16, 17]])
```

But if you want to get all rows of one certain column you have to use **dimensional indexing**:

```
x[y == 1, 0] # all rows of feature1 (0 index) corresponding to class 1

array([ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16])
```

So here `y == 1` is all rows and `0` is index of column you are interested in.